# Should this special case question (that has a proof) be marked as a duplicate of the general case question (that doesn't have a proof)?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

I recently found this question: [Proof of the Existence of All Phone Numbers in Pi](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3495590/proof-of-the-existence-of-all-phone-numbers-in-pi)

I understand why it can be seen as a duplicate of [Does π contain all possible number combinations?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216343/does-pi-contain-all-possible-number-combinations), but the question is much more specific and there is a proof that doesn't need π to be a normal number: a proof by exhaustion.

As discussed in [my comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3495590/proof-of-the-existence-of-all-phone-numbers-in-pi#comment10099465_3495590), since the early 2000s, we know enough digits of π to prove that it contains all 10-digit number sequences with an exhaustive search. However, this proof wouldn't make sense as an answer to the question on all possible number combinations.

Related question: [Should questions about special cases of a more general problem be marked (closed) as duplicate?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28808/should-questions-about-special-cases-of-a-more-general-problem-be-marked-closed)

Comment: No. The question on all possible number combinations has no answer to the question on all phone numbers, so “This question already has answers here” is wrong. If there was a proof that pi is normal, then it answered the latter, but that is open.

Comment: I think you have a good point, but this meta question should really go into the Request for Reopen Votes thread: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34447/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-volume-01-2022-today.

Comment: @MaoWao Thanks for letting me know, I wasn't aware of that procedure. I've added it here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/35942/477462